# How does the pressure loss of the SimpleGenericOrifice in OpenModelica work?

Tags: fluid, modelica, openmodelica

If I model a simple pipe with :

- pressure and temperature boundary conditions for the inlet (`Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT`)
- mass flow rate and temperature bondary conditions for the outlet (`Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T`)

It results with a certain regular pressure loss in my pipe.
Now  I add a `SimpleGenericOrifice` from the `Modelica Standard Library` ,with parameters : `diameter`, `m_flow_nominal` and `dp_nominal`, to modify the pressure loss of this network, without modifying the parameter of the previous network. If I have more pressure losses, I'd expect to have a modified mass flow rate, however it's not the case.

To give more context, I want to use the SimpleGenericOrifice because to model a part of my hydraulic network, I use the `Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe` component, which is not the case in reality so I'd like to adjust the pressure loss with test results , because in my model I have almost no pressure loss.

Can someone help me understand the mechanism of this component ?

Best regards,
Maxime

Answer (score 1):

> If I have more pressure losses, I'd expect to have a modified mass flow rate, however it's not the case.

Since you are using `Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T` as a boundary value the mass flow rate will be unchanged, but the outlet pressure (at the mass flow source) will drop.

If you want to see a change in flow as you add an orifice in series with the pipe, you should replace the mass flow source with a pressure source (`Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT`)